# Non-participation bias: weighting for the inverse of the sampling fraction

Tags: survey, bias, epidemiology, bias-correction

[This](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27899002) and other studies, where only a proportion of people return a completed questionnaire, suffer from non-participation bias. I have previously just compared participants with non-participants to see if there are any systematic differences and comment on them. However, the study in the link uses "weighting for the inverse of the sampling fraction" which I am not familiar with. Can anyone share any wisdom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your information suggests that $50\%$ of men complete the survey and $80\%$ of women complete the survey.

Then you might weight the actual responses by men by $\frac{1}{0.5}=2$ and the responses by women by $\frac{1}{0.8}= 1.25$

Comment: Thank you @Henry. Suppose the responders are 80% male but the total sample has 50% males? Or, more complex still, suppose responders have a mean age of 30 but the total sample mean age is 20? How would one approach these scenarios?

Comment: The natural approach would be to try to get the weighted samples to reflect the population distribution as far as possible on things that matter (which may be age and gender).  A risk is that you end up with small sub-samples in particular categories, so the only teenage boy who could be bothered to fill up the form might get heavily overweighted despite being unusual